# Desenvolver um projeto MVC com Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Alguém me pede para desenvolver uma aplicação em MVC com vários elementos tecnológicos, como Angular, Bootstrap, Entity e etc. Eu então crio um projeto Web API, posso garantir para essa pessoa que está desenvolvido em MVC? Isso é apenas conceitual.

Comment: Seu principal problema é a comunicação entre você e o cliente. Existe diferença entre pedir para utilizar o padrão de arquitetura MVC e utilizar o ASP.NET MVC Framework.

Comment: É um teste apenas, não é um cliente. Estou parado e resolvi fazer o teste, com direito a consulta. Me deu 4 dias para terminar. É uma empresa do ramo de Transporte e Logística. Como nunca misturei essas tecnologias, começou apresentar dúvidas. Estou tentando tirar todas as dúvidas possíveis para depois meter a mão na massa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC é um design de projeto que conceitua a separação em *Model*, *View* e *Controller*.

No ASP.NET Web API, nós temos separado o *Model* e o *Controller*, não chegamos a desenvolver uma visualização para o usuário, mas se você tratar o resultado do endpoint criado como a *View*, então podemos dizer que o Web API é um design de projeto que implementa o MVC.

No entanto nunca me surgiu esse tipo de questionamento se poderia definir o desenvolvimento em Web API como se ele utilizasse o padrão de projeto MVC.

Comment: Normalmente usamo a API para desenvolvimento de serviços, que não tem uma view. Porém podemos sim, definir uma interface, já que no template gerado é criado um folder View.